# Update offline webpages without updating app

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have an app which contains html files which i am displaying using a webview. This html files are nothing but documentation the users of my app require. My question is, can I update these html files without asking the user to update the entire app? I dont want to replace these html files by hosting the documentaion online.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do one of these:

1. Update your app (which is what you don't want)
2. Host the raw .html files on a web server, and whenever the user opens the app, check if there are new files available and download them.
3. Simply create a website that shows the .html files and open the
   website in your app (which i'm guessing is what you don't want
   either)

So you're left with option 2.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, yes #2 seems logical. Can you give me brief example on how to get on with that?

Answer (score 0):

To update files without requiring an app update, you will need the app to obtain the HTML content online.

One option, which you mentioned you don't want, is loading a URL into the `WebView` rather than local HTML files.

The other option would involve hosting the web pages somewhere and the app would download them. The only benefit of this I can see, is that if the device is offline is can use the last obtained HTML file. You could just use caching to achieve this though.

Answer (score 0):

How complicated are the webpages? Using JSON is another method.

Comment: they have javascript and image assets. so a little complicated